# Populate() mongoose só retorna ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Imagino que seja algo bem simples de resolver mas já estou a várias horas tentando resolver e não chego a lugar nenhum.

Estou desenvolvendo um blog como forma de estudo porém estou tendo problemas ao utilizar o `populate()` do mongoose.

Tenho os seguintes models:

**Posts.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    title:
    {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    category:
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'categories',
        required: true
    },
    text:
    {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('posts', PostSchema)
```

**Categories.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
    title:
    {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('categories', CategorySchema)
```

E o código para mostrar todos os posts feitos, inclusive com o titulo da categoria:

**IndexController.js**

```
const Post = require('../models/Posts');

exports.Index = (req, res) =>
{
    Post.find({}).
    populate('categories').
    exec((err, post) =>
    {
        res.json(post);
    })
}
```

O problema é que o único retorno que tenho é do `id` da categoria:

```
[{"_id":"60198923d4323f3630468fce",
"title":"Titulo qualquer",
"category":"60198651822d5147c041eaee",
"text":"Texto qualquer","__v":0}]
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que se erro esteja em `Post.find({}).populate('categories')...`, pois o correto seria passar para o método `populate` a "coluna", por assim dizer, que você deseja popular. Você deveria passar `category` ao invés de `categories`. Desta forma:

```
 Post.find({}).
//              ↓↓↓ vamos popular este campo "category"
    populate('category').
    exec((err, post) =>
    {
        res.json(post);
    })
```

A própria [documentação do mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population) nos dá um exemplo:

Schemas e models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
// ↓↓↓  propriedade do documento faz referência ao Story.
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
// ↓↓↓  propriedade do documento faz referência ao Person. 
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

Veja que `author`, nome da propriedade do documento, é uma referência ao model de `Person` e quando ele vai fazer o `populate` e passar o nome desta "coluna" para o método:

```
Story.
  findOne({ title: 'Casino Royale' }).
//           ↓↓↓ vamos popular este campo "author"
  populate('author').
  exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);
    // prints "The author is Ian Fleming"
  });
```